# Heavy Check Mark Not Showing In Email As It Does In HTML

Tags: html, unicode, outlook, emoji

I originally inquired about this [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223970/how-to-create-an-html-check-not-checkbox-with-border-and-color-fill) and got my answer for regular HTML, however the following code does NOT show the same when sent via email:

```html
<div style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10004;</div>
<div style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10004;</div>
<div style="color:green; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10004;</div>
```

This is because it appears [Microsoft sees it as an emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43308602/10474024).

I've tried the following to the code, but nothing changes:

```
<div class="unicode" style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10004;</div>
```

All I get is the default:

[image: example image]

Here is the jinja2 template I am currently using/tweaking trying to get this to work (see tbody section):

```
jinja_tmplt = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en-US\">
{% for html_CI in html_CI_list %}
    {% set columns = html_CI.tech_DF.columns.values[1:] %}
    <h1>{{ html_CI.tech_grp }}</h1><br/>
    {{ html_CI.tech_DF.to_html(index=False) }}<br>
    <style>.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #ABC233;} .table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #6CC04A;}</style>
        <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr style="text-align: center;">
                {% for col_hdr in columns %}
                    <th style="background-color: #005C21; text-align: center; color:white">{{ col_hdr }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for row in html_CI.tech_DF.itertuples() %}
                    <tr style="text-align: center;">
                    {% for elem_data in row[2:] %}
                        {% set loop_num = loop.index0 %}
                        {% if loop_num == 0 %}
                            <td>{{ elem_data }}</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td><div style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10004;</div></td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
{% endfor %}
</html>"""
```

Please note that the table coloring in style also works in HTML but not email.

Comment: You could try using [Emoji variation sequences](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji//11.0/emoji-variation-sequences.txt). For instance, a heavy check mark as text would be `&#10004;&#xFE0E;`, while the same as an emoji would be `&#10004;&#xFE0F;` See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zay9qgL6/). No idea if this works for your specific situation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only option is to use ... None of the above would work specific to my needs.

I did need to use the following code, but none of the other options (div and such) would work for email.

```
&#10003;
```

Here is the Jinja used ... put them together:

1. Header
2. Style
3. template
4. footer

Here is the code...

```
JINJA_HDR = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=\"en-US\">"""

JINJA_FTR = """</html>"""


def get_style():
    """


    """

    html_style = """<style>
            table.greenCisco {
              border: 2px solid #005C21;
              background-color: #6CC04A;
              width: 100%;
              text-align: center;
              border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background: #ABC233;
            }
            tr:nth-child(odd) {
                background: #6CC04A;
            }
            table.greenCisco td, table.greenCisco th {
              border: 2px solid #000000;
              padding: 3px 2px;
            }
            table.greenCisco tbody td {
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            table.greenCisco thead {
              background: #005C21;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
            }
            table.greenCisco thead th {
              font-size: 15px;
              font-weight: bold;
              color: #FFFFFF;
              text-align: center;
              border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
            }
            table.blueTable tfoot {
              font-size: 13px;
              font-weight: bold;
              color: #FFFFFF;
              background: #D0E4F5;
              text-align: center;
              border-top: 2px solid #444444;
            }
        </style>"""

    return html_style

def get_Jinja(df_list:list):
    """
    This function takes in a list of DataFrames and returns 
    a Jinja parsed string of table data used in email.

    """

    # skipping checking the input for now - kkeeton 20190122
    jinja_tmplt = """{% for html_CI in html_CI_list %}
        {% set columns = html_CI.tech_DF.columns.values[1:] %}
        <h1>{{ html_CI.tech_grp }}</h1><br/>
        <table class="greenCisco">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                {% for col_hdr in columns %}
                    <th>{{ col_hdr }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for row in html_CI.tech_DF.itertuples() %}
                    {% set row_num = loop.index0 %}
                    {% if row_num % 2 == 0 %}
                        <tr bgcolor="#ABC233">
                    {% else %}
                        <tr bgcolor="#6CC04A">
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for elem_data in row[2:] %}
                        {% set loop_num = loop.index0 %}
                        {% if loop_num == 0 %}
                            <td>{{ elem_data }}</td>
                        {% else %}
                            {% if elem_data == 0 %}
                                <td><div style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</div></td>
                            {% elif elem_data == 1 %}
                                <td><div style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</div></td>
                            {% elif elem_data == 2 %}
                                <td><div style="color:green; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</div></td>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot valign="center">
                <tr colspan="0"><span style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>Pending</b> <span style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>In Progress</b> <span style="color:green; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>Complete</b></tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}"""

    return jinja_tmplt
```

Answer (score 2):

`:before` will not work with Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo or notes.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/before/

The following check-marks work well in every major email client. They can be resized and colored. Their exact look might vary because of the email client or the font used to display them:

- ✓ `&#x2713;` - Check Mark
- ✔ `&#x2714;` - Heavy Check Mark

Sample coloring:

`<span style="color: #ff0000;">&#x2713; - Check Mark: red </span>`

`<span style="color: #0000ff;">&#x2714; - Heavy Check Mark: blue</span>`

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work. It gives the same green checkmark.

Comment: @KassandraKeeton I want to help because it makes me a better email developer. I am not running jinja2. My guess something else in the template is affecting this. I tested this in Litmus using Outlook 2002-2019 and it worked fine. I was able to run it unmodified, color it with no issues. It worked in every major email client. I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pseudo-elements](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/using-pseudo-elements-to-progressively-enhance-your-emails/)

Have you tried:

> ```
> div::before {
>   content:'\2714';
> }
> ```

Try all of the checkmarks maybe there are some that aren't considered emoji:

> ```
> \2611   &#9745;
> \2705   &#9989;
> \2713   &#10003;
> \2714   &#10004;
> \1f5f8  &#128504;
> \1f5f9  &#128505;
> ```

### Demo

```css
div::before {
  content:'\2714';
}
```

```html
<div style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;"></div>
<div style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;"></div>
<div style="color:green; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;"></div>
```

Comment: I'll try, but will that not have an impact on other places of my code?

Comment: Yes, all divs, you should use a class.

Comment: how exactly am I supposed to add that into HTML? It just acts like it's regular string.

Comment: I added it into style as seen here:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/div-tag-html/

But now the checkboxes are empty.

Comment: Try copy-paste this: ✔

Comment: That takes me back to square one because of the issue I mention in my original post. :(

Comment: It's also not a button, so not sure if that matters for your example (the link you provided talks about buttons)

Comment: Well if it's a certain range that are considered emoji then try all of the checkmarks perhaps you'll find one that isn't considered one. See update.